# selectNodes(), selectSingleNode() functions in crm 2013

Tags: crm

Can anyone tell me what are the replacements for selectNodes(), selectSingleNode() functions in XrmServiceToolKit. and how to use them in crm 2013.

Regards,

Nagaraju

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two methods below:

```
function selectNodes(node, XPathExpression) {
    if (typeof (node.selectNodes) != "undefined") {
        return node.selectNodes(XPathExpression);
    }
    else {
        var output = [];
        var XPathResults = node.evaluate(XPathExpression, node, _NSResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = XPathResults.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            output.push(result);
            result = XPathResults.iterateNext();
        }
        return output;
    }
}

function selectSingleNodeText(node, xpathExpr) {
    var x = selectSingleNode(node, xpathExpr);
    if (_isNodeNull(x))
    { return null; }
    if (typeof (x.text) != "undefined") {
        return x.text;
    }
    else {
        return x.textContent;
    }
}

function _isNodeNull(node) {
    if (node == null)
    { return true; }
    if ((node.attributes.getNamedItem("i:nil") != null) && (node.attributes.getNamedItem("i:nil").value == "true"))
    { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent update uses jQuery to make selections from XML documents to allow for non-Internet Explorer browsers.  Make sure that you have the latest XrmServiceToolkit javascript library.